# Evaluate definite integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{a+\cos^2 x}\ dx$

Tags: calculus

How to Evaluate:

### $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{a+\cos^2 x}\ dx$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $\cos^2 x = \frac12(1+\cos 2x)$ and the variable change $t=\tan^2 x$ to integrate,

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{dx}{a+\cos^2 x}=\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{at^2+(a+1)}$$
$$=\frac1{\sqrt{a(a+1)}}\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac a{a+1}}t\right)_0^\infty=\frac{\pi/2}{\sqrt{a(a+1)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is the indefinite one:
$\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}\tan\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{a+1}}\right)}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+1}}$
But I can't find any numerical answer.